# In \DeclareStringOption, what is the difference between <init> and <default>?

Tags: package-writing, package-options, kvoptions

In the `kvoptions` package the following macro is defined:

```
\DeclareStringOption [⟨init⟩] {⟨key⟩} [⟨default⟩]
```

Following is the related documentation:

> A macro is created that remembers the value of the key ⟨key⟩. The name
>   of the macro consists of the option name ⟨key⟩ that is prefixed by the
>   prefix (see 2.1.3). The initial contents of the macro can be given by
>   the first optional argument ⟨init⟩. The default is empty. The the
>   option ⟨key⟩ is defined. The option code just stores its value in the
>   macro. If the optional argument at the end of `\DeclareStringOption` is
>   given, then option ⟨key⟩ is defined with the default ⟨default⟩.

I fail to understand what is the difference between the `default` value and the `init` one. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In common with many keyval methods, the *default* value is the one which will be used if only the key name is given at point of use. Thus with

```
\DeclareStringOption{foo}[bar]
```

giving `foo` with no value/`=` sign in the option list is equivalent to giving `foo = bar`.

In contrast, the initial value is used to ensure that some value has been stored before option processing. Thus

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypkg}
\DeclareStringOption[baz]{foo}
```

will store the value `baz` for key `foo` 'now'. This is equivalent to giving

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypkg}
\DeclareStringOption{foo}
\newcommand*{\mypkg@foo}{baz}
```

If the user then sets the `foo` option, the initial value will be 'thrown away' and has no more influence on the outcome. In contrast, the default value is still important as in the case

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypkg}
\DeclareStringOption[baz]{foo}[bar]
```

If the user does not give the `foo` option, then `\mypkg@foo` will have value `baz`. If the user gives the `foo` option with no value, the default is used and `\mypkg@foo` will have value `bar`. Finally, if the user gives `foo = <some value>` then of course `\mypkg@foo` will contain `<some value>`.

Comment: Just to make sure: `\DeclareStringOption{foo}` defines a macro `\mypkg@foo` that will expand to `bar` given the call `\usepackage[foo=bar]{mypkg}`. Is that correct?

Comment: Another point: Is it correct to think of the initial value as the default one (in the sense that it is the one that will be if the user provided nothing)?

Comment: @Dror Yes, `\DeclareStringOption{foo}` defines `\mypkg@foo`, initially to be empty unless you give the `[<init>]` optional argument. The initial value is used if the user doesn't use the key at all.